# Topology on integers making it a topological group

Tags: topological-groups

Are there non-trivial topologies (neither discrete nor indiscrete) on the additive group of integers $\mathbb{Z}$, making it into a topological group.
Could someone list them all, possibly with some details?

Comment: May I ask why you posted this? thanks.

Comment: Actually, I was trying to prove that with Fürstenburg's topology, $\mathbb{Z}$ is a topological group. Then this question came to my mind.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For any set $S$ of primes, the embedding

$$\mathbb{Z} \to \prod_{p \in S} \mathbb{Z}_p$$

of $\mathbb{Z}$ into the corresponding product of rings of [$p$-adic integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number) gives a nontrivial topology on $\mathbb{Z}$ generated by arithmetic progressions of length $d$ where all prime divisors of $D$ lie in $S$. All of these topologies are distinct. When $S$ is the entire set of primes, we get the topology induced from the [profinite completion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profinite_group), notably used in [Fürstenburg's proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%BCrstenberg%27s_proof_of_the_infinitude_of_primes) of the infinitude of the primes.

More generally one can take the [initial topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_topology) with respect to any collection of quotients $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ where $n$ is chosen from a set $S$ of positive integers closed under taking divisors and $\text{lcm}$s. (It is generated by arithmetic progressions of length chosen from $S$.)

Comment: Thanks Yuan. Are these all the topologies making $\mathbb{Z}$ into a topologial group.

Comment: Thanks Yuan. Your answer is very helpful. I think that there might be examples of finite topological groups with non-trivial topology.

Comment: Continuing Quaochu Y's comment: we could easily rationalize demanding that a sane topology on $\mathbb Z$ should make the quotient maps to (discrete?!) $\mathbb Z/n$ continuous, which implies that the map factors through $\lim_n \mathbb Z/n=\hat{\mathbb Z}$, which discretizes $\mathbb Z$. Dropping various sets of primes dividing the $n$'s produces other effects.

Comment: +1: Nice characterisation of Fürstenburg's topology! But how do we know that these topologies are compatible with the group operations?

Comment: @Zhen: they're initial with respect to topologies on the finite quotients which are compatible with group operations (either discrete or indiscrete).

Comment: What is he image of $k\in \Bbb Z$ in first embedding?

Comment: @user138171: I don't understand the question. It's the same as the image of $\mathbb{Z}$ in any ring (necessarily unique), namely the multiples of the identity.

Comment: so $k\mapsto k\Bbb 1$ where $\Bbb 1$ is the identity element of the ring.

Comment: @user138171: yes, that's the unique possibility for a unital ring homomorphism out of $\mathbb{Z}$.